# iPhone Next Backup Size Bigger Than Total Of All Apps Being Backed Up

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup

A while back, my iPhone (running iOS 14.4.2) stopped backing up to iCloud as I was running out of space. When I went into the backups section of the app to see how much data my next backup will take up, I saw this...

[image]

... The "Next Backup Size" is showing as 8.52GB.

The sum of each individual app's backup size is much less than the next backup size that is being shown. The apps are listed in descending order of backup size, the total backup size that I counted is around 300MB.

I tried looking online only to find a lot of people having a similar issue to me, the most common solutions were disabling iCloud photos and remove files stored locally on the iPhone through the files app.

My photos are not being backed up to iCloud, and I've tried removing everything stored on my iPhone and even tried uninstalling the Files app completely. Nothing is fixing my problem. With none of the solutions working for me, I have come here.

What do you think is causing this issue and how do I go about fixing this?

Comment: Whenever I have problems with iCloud Backup I click the "Delete Backup", then enable it and let it complete a new initial backup. Note that you'll need to disable all the apps you've disabled, as that gets reset. Possibly look into your phone's local storage, is there anything that's 5-7GB big?

Comment: I tried deleting the previous backup but that didn't fix things. I have 100GB worth of photos and videos, but that can't be it as I've set iCloud to not backup that. Other than that, I have 5.1GB worth of data in Messages, could that be it? I've set the Messages app to not use iCloud though

Comment: messages has essentially 2 iCloud options - one is to sync via iCloud. If that's not selected, the other is to back up to iCloud as a part of your phone's backup. That sounds like the issue here. You can't disable this unfortunately, so you'll need to delete some messages off your phone, or backup to iTunes.

Comment: Yup, that is the case. I tested it out by deleting a few old conversations and the backup size started going down. If the sync messages to iCloud option is disabled, then messages are backed up via iCloud backups. This is an issue as the same conversations will be backed up multiple times through different devices. So I bought the 50GB iCloud subscription and enabled the backup messages through iCloud. That seems to have fixed things as messages are only backed up ones.